# Problem connecting with Mongoose - TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having some trouble connecting to Mongoose in my React app. I am trying to connect an Azure Cosmos DB instance with Mongo API.

Here is my app.js:

```
import React from 'react';


const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbUri = `SecretDBConnectionString`
mongoose.createConnection(dbUri, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(console.log('MongoDB Connected..'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));


class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I get this error:

TypeError: mongoose.createConnection is not a function

I have googled the error but have not found something pertaining to my situation. I feel like I am missing something very basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further research I have learned that you can not initialize MongoDB from the client side.